# Regex pattern for username in react form

Tags: reactjs

I have made a react form, for usernames and passwords, and have a regex form to validate them.

I have a set state, to first set the value, then I pass in a callback to setState to then verify that the username is correct.

```
onChange={(e) => this.setState({username: e.target.value}, this.usernameValidator(this.state.username))}
```

I use the setState callback because I know it will be called each time something is changed, I'm not sure if I should call the method separately?

here is my handler

```
  usernameValidator = (username) =>{
var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
if(usernameRegex.test(username)){
  this.setState({
    isUsernameCorrect: true
  })
}else{
  this.setState({
    isUsernameCorrect: false
  })
}
  console.log(this.state.isUsernameCorrect)
}
```

my issue is that, whenever a user types for example 5 characters, which is passable to the regex pattern, and then deletes any number of characters, to an unacceptable number, the regex pattern will still pass.

How come this is happening, I mean onChange, should also check for deletions, and then the handler would validate again?

EDIT:

after comments, saying It's the regex pattern that is the problem i tried, using some console logs, to find the value of the current state, when It's validated

```
usernameValidator = (username) =>{
var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
if(usernameRegex.test(username)){
  this.setState({
    isUsernameCorrect: true
  }, console.log('correct'))
}else if(!usernameRegex.test(username)){
  this.setState({
    isUsernameCorrect: false
  }, console.log('not correct'))
}
  console.log(this.state.isUsernameCorrect)
  console.log(username)
}
```

it always logs, the username, before the next key is typed so for example if the given username is `DDD`
the passed in value will be `DD` because it gives in the username before the value is changed

Comment: Your regex is malformed for your purposes - it passes with just two characters: https://regex101.com/

Comment: i figured the issue, is that since the state is asynchronous the passed in suername, will be the previous state, and therefore not render the current
e.target.value

Comment: The issue is with your regex. You have three elements to your regex. Your first character has to be either a letter or a number, and you can have one or more of these. Your next capture is more broad, but you can have zero of these. The final capture must be one or more of letter/number. So any two digit password that is letters and/or numbers would pass this regex. What pattern are you trying to force?

Comment: I recreated your post here: https://codesandbox.io/s/llzlxoj7p7   Try creating a more strict regex, and I suspect it'll address your issue

Comment: I edited the quieston after researching more

Comment: Lux your solution in the codesandbox works well, you can post it as answer, and i will accept it

Comment: Your `onChange` code is incorrect. Look at the sandbox that @lux posted to see how to correctly write it.

Comment: the problem was, that i passed the other function in as a callback to setState, so the function would not receive the updated state in. Thank you lux for your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting how the callback after `setState` is invoked. At current, it's invoked immediately rather than as a proper callback; the latter of which is guaranteed to get called after `setState` has updated the `state`:

**Current**

```
onChange(e) {
  this.setState({
    username: e.target.value
    }, 
    this.usernameValidator(this.state.username)
  )
}
```

**Suggested (https://codesandbox.io/s/llzlxoj7p7)**

```
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      {
        username: e.target.value
      },
      () => this.usernameValidator(this.state.username)
    );
  }
```

It's also worth taking a second pass at the regex to ensure it's doing exactly what you'd expect. https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for this. It also has a great cheat sheet for reducing the complexity of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to something like `[\w\d]`, which is all word and digit characters.